# ¿Cómo consigo la respuesta en el componente desde el dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Tengo un componente el cual tiene un formulario donde al momento de hacer click al botón de Submit mando a llamar una función llamada `handleSubmit` (qué está en mi componente), el cual por medio de `dispatch` llama un action y este action, manda a llamar a un servicio (HTTP Request).

Lo que me gustaría es poder obtener la respuesta en el componente para poder hacer validaciones pero como la petición es asíncrona nunca puedo obtener la respuesta y me la imprime como undefined. ¿Cómo puedo obtener la respuesta?

---

**handleSubmit**

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const { validateFields } = this.props.form;

   validateFields((err, params) => {
       if (!err) {
            const { user, dispatch } = this.props;

            let response = dispatch(actions.addDevice(params))
            console.log(response); //Response is undefined
       }
    });
}
```

**actions.addDevice**

```
function addDevice(params){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let { authentication } = getState();
        dispatch(request({}));

        service.addDevice(params, authentication.user.access_token)
            .then(
                response => {
                    if(response.status === 201) {
                        dispatch(success(response.data));
                    }
                    return response;
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
                }
            )
    }

    function request(response) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_REQUEST, response } }
    function success(response) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_SUCCESS, response } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

**service.addDevice**

```
function addDevice(params, token){
    return axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/user/add-device',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
        data: {
            data1: params.data1,
            data2: params.data2,
            data3: params.data3
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        return error.response;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te falta son dos pasos muy sencillos, retornar y esperar que se ejecute la promesa. Te explico:

En tu función de `addDevice` que es el action, debes retornar algo, si no retornas nada, por eso obtienes `undefined`. Así que puedes retornar la promesa, quedando algo así:

```
function addDevice(params){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let { authentication } = getState();
    dispatch(request({}));

    // -----> AQUI agregas el return <------
    return service.addDevice(params, authentication.user.access_token)
      .then(
        response => {
          if(response.status === 201) {
            dispatch(success(response.data));
          }
          return response;
        },
        error => {
          dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
            dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
          }
        )
  ...
}
```

Ya luego es cuestión de hacerla "theneable". Pero antes para hacer tu código mucho más "prettier" puedes utilizar algo que te proporciona `redux` al momento de conectar un componente, y se conoce como el `mapDispatchToProps`, que es el segundo parámetro que recibe la función `connect`. Básicamente lo que esta función hace es retornar un objeto con propiedades para tu componente que hagan uso del método `dispatch`. Y se implementa así:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addDevice: (params) => dispatch(actions.addDevice(params))
});

// se agrega al connect
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TuComponente)
```

> **Nota:** Recuerda que es el segundo parámetro de la función `connect` el primer parámetro se suele llamar `mapStateToProps` y lo que recibe como parámetro no es el `dispatch` si no el `state` en si

Y luego ya queda llamarlo en tu función de una forma más limpia y "theneable":

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const { validateFields } = this.props.form;

  validateFields((err, params) => {
    if (!err) {
      const { user, dispatch } = this.props;

      // recuerda que la función se llama `addDevice` y ahora está en `this.props`
      this.props.addDevice(params).then(response => {
        // Aquí tu response
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**BONUS**

También puedes usar `async` y `await` para no ser tan "thenpendiente". Una forma en la que quedaría bien sería redefinir tu método `handleSubmit` así:

```
async handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const { validateFields } = this.props.form;

  validateFields(async (err, params) => {
    if (!err) {
      const { user, dispatch } = this.props;

      // una forma mucho más bonita y funciona igual
      const response = await this.props.addDevice(params);
    }
  });
}
```